# Detect if string has only one occurrence of a number

Tags: java

If I have a string like `"/hello/world:123/foo-bar"`, how would I find the number of occurrences of say `123`? One way would be to create a `Pattern` with a regex and then a `Matcher` with a counter. But is there is better way, say a one liner?

Answer (score 6):

Try [StringUtils.countMatches](http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-lang/javadocs/api-2.6/org/apache/commons/lang/StringUtils.html#countMatches%28java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String%29)

```
StringUtils.countMatches(input,"123");
```

or

```
while ((index = value.indexOf(findValue, index)) != -1)
        {
            count++;
            index += findValue.length();
        }
```

Answer (score 5):

You could try

```
"test 123 test".split("123").length - 1; // 1
```

Or more generally

```
String yourString = "something", searchString = "ome";
yourString.split(searchString).length - 1;
```

Answer (score 4):

You may check if the result of `String.indexOf("123")` and `String.lastIndexOf("123")` is same. If yes then there is only one occurrence.